# php - issue with assigning session value

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a piece of code that is checking to see if a session ID has been set for my site, and if it hasn't, it assigns it a value from my URL.  Below is the code I have:

```
if (!$_SESSION['test_id']){
  $_SESSION['test_id'] = strip_tags($_REQUEST["id"]);
};
```

My problem is not a huge one, but I am getting a notice that says:

```
Undefined index: test_id
```

Is there a better way assign this variable without setting off the notice?  This piece fo code is in an Expression Engine platform (Code Igniter) so I don't have total control over the display of notices.  This particular page has all error reporting turned off in my code, but it is still showing up.

Thanks so much for any help!

Comment: This question is tagged CodeIgniter. Why aren't you using the [Session Class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Test it against `isset()` as well. That will get rid of the notice.

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['test_id']) && !$_SESSION['test_id']){
  $_SESSION['test_id'] = strip_tags($_REQUEST["id"]);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

yes.. you can do it.. using `isset()`

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['test_id']))
```

This is because 'test_id' doesn't exist when you check if exists.. and with `isset` is not creating it...

Answer (score 0):

You should try 
 if(!isset($_SESSION['...'])) { }

or 
 if(!empty($_SESSION['...')) { }

Answer (score 0):

The equivilant code to what you are looking for is:

```
if (!empty($_SESSION['test_id']))
```

The `isset($foo) && !$foo` is logically equivilant to `!empty()`.  Empty is a language construct, just like `isset`, but it also checks that it's a non-empty value.

So there's no need for the extract condition, just toss the `!empty` there, and you're golden...